# How to make webpage build dynamically based on previous clicked link?

Tags: html, sql, dynamic, web

I am setting up a website where you click a category which takes you to a page listing various items under that category. How can I make it where after a user selects a category the webpage is dynamically built around that category. Example: After clicking Beer category the next page will say "List of Beer", had they clicked wine it would say "List of Wine."

Comment: With a server-side scripting language, such as [tag:php], [tag:ruby], [tag:asp.net] (among *many* others)...what do you have available?

Comment: Would it be possible to accomplish this with either HTML or javascript?

Comment: You could use JavaScript to load new content into the current page, or static HTML to create new pages (but those pages would have to be, each of them, separately maintained, which is a nightmare). The JavaScript option would meet your 'dynamic' requirement, certainly. Would you require plain JavaScript, or are you able to use a library? And, if you're interested in a JavaScript solution, what's your current ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) HTML mark-up?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to setup some sort of data store, with a retrieval method.

For example, you could create a datastore (SQL, XML, etc.), and put services on top of it (in this case, your service might be /category/{name}). Then, your web page could call that service, and dynamically display the data from the data store.

There are some great resources out there to help you get started, like codeigniter (php), spring (java), and ASP.NET MVC